# Pd.todate time comparison not working python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to assign a value based on a max date of 11-15-2023. As you can see in the column where the max date is stored, several are on both sides of the cut off date, yet only the else statement will assign a value. It seems that there could be an issue with the way I've written the date that the comparison is not working.  I've tried adding the 0's for the time, but it will give me an error about invalid syntax. Any ideas ?

```
out1['churned']=np.where(out1['time']<=pd.to_datetime(2034-11-15),1,0)
```

[image]

the datatype is datetime64[ns]

Comment: did you mean `pd.Timestamp("2034-11-15")`?

Comment: yup, that was it. that worked.